# Does NEST support script-based sorting?

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

Here's the ElasticSearch query I'd like to build using [NEST](https://github.com/Mpdreamz/NEST):

```
{
    "from": 0,
    "size": 10,
    "sort": {
        "_script": {
            "script": "doc['name'].value=='my perfect match' ? 1 : 0",
            "type" : "number",
            "order" : "desc"
        },
        "_score": {}
    },
    "query": {
       ....
    }
}
```

(simplified - really I'm sorting by a few more attributes. The point of the script-based sort is to promote exact matches to the top of the result set.)

Explicitly sorting by _score is not a problem...

```
.Sort(sort => sort.OnField("_score"))
```

... but NEST doesn't seem to have an equivalent operator for the script-based sort yet - or does it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NEST supports script sorts through `SortScript()`

See the unit tests for them here:

https://github.com/Mpdreamz/NEST/blob/master/src/Nest.Tests.Unit/Search/Sort/SortTests.cs#L171